# WebService serialization and xsi:type attribute

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, soap

I'm writting a webservice client (C# / .NET 4.0 / VS2010) and I have an issue while serializing.
I managed to subscribe to the service using 'Add a service Reference', but I noticed an error when the request is sent over SOAP.

What I want to send (and what the server expect to receive) is that :

```
<param>
    <name>MyParamName</name>
    <value>
        <string>MyParamValue</string>
    </value>
</param>
```

When I watch the request sent by .NET in Wireshark, I get the following :

```
<param>
    <name>MyParamName</name>
    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">MyParamValue</value>
</param>
```

Is there a way to force VS2010 or the .NET serializer to replace xsi:type attribute by the real tag ?